# How do i fix this Timeout issue during Initialization

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I created a Catering Invoice Creator web app with flask.
It works perfect on VS Code, but I am having issues with deployment.
I am using Git Hub to Zeet with AWS cloud.

I am able to build and deploy. But when I visit the deployment I get this error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503
Runtime Log:

```
START RequestId: d5c93f92-8545-49fd-b522-fd6656c35699 Version: 5

2024-02-28T17:31:47.171Z d5c93f92-8545-49fd-b522-fd6656c35699 Task timed out after 60.05 seconds


END RequestId: d5c93f92-8545-49fd-b522-fd6656c35699

REPORT RequestId: d5c93f92-8545-49fd-b522-fd6656c35699  Duration: 60053.94 ms   Billed Duration: 60000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory
 Used: 31 MB    

INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 10000.01 ms  Phase: init Status: timeout

INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 60037.38 ms  Phase: invoke   Status: timeout

START RequestId: 1efef1f6-1eed-432b-8fee-190b6e9dba5c Version: 5

2024-02-28T17:32:27.783Z 1efef1f6-1eed-432b-8fee-190b6e9dba5c Task timed out after 60.06 seconds


END RequestId: 1efef1f6-1eed-432b-8fee-190b6e9dba5c

REPORT RequestId: 1efef1f6-1eed-432b-8fee-190b6e9dba5c  Duration: 60058.11 ms   Billed Duration: 60000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory
 Used: 32 MB    

INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 10003.32 ms  Phase: init Status: timeout

Zeet © 2024
```

I have already fixed compatibility issues with modules.
Tried to start a chat on Zeet no response.
Maybe it is because I need a server?
PS My first Deployment

Comment: What is your Lambda function doing during INIT? Where is your code? Do you know how to configure networking for Lambda functions (assuming that you're using VPC)?

Comment: https://github.com/DanielSeaton4110/5Cater

Comment: Thank you for the response and assistance.   If you want to look at my code: https://github.com/DanielSeaton4110/5Cater                                                                                     As of now I don't know how to configure Lambda but i see it. Look like I need to configure a few things like the VPC and permissions.

Comment: What AWS infrastructure is created/deployed by Zeet, beyond a Lambda function? A 503 response suggests some kind of throttling or that your Lambda function, if behind API Gateway, exceeded the maximum integration timeout (which is 29 seconds). That might be because the Lambda function itself is trying to make some outbound network API request but has no valid networking path to the desired destination. Anyway, that all aside, there's not enough information and insufficiently detailed logs here to diagnose further so you'll need to dig into this more.